# This type of page is not served when accessing an asp page in debug mode in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, iis-6

I am trying to debug an old project in Visual Studio 2008. When I go to an asp page I get the following.

```
Server Error in '/website' Application.

This type of page is not served.

Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

I have checked IIS (version 6) and Active Server Pages are allowed. I can get the page to appear in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are actually using the IIS6 to serve the page and not the development web server that comes with vs2008 which only serves static and .NET content.

In IIS manager open the properties dialog on the folder that contains the ASP file, is Script enabled.  Also check at the website or server level whether there is a mapping for .asp extension to the ASP.dll.